# Spring Batch: Map another table to a batch job

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

I'm currently wondering if I'm creating a lot of boilerplate for nothing. Spring Batch seems to be all about jobs and large data working. I have created my own jobs database table and am working it off with a @Scheduled annotation, so basically just a process on another thread. The job reads rows from a database table, does stuff with it and then writes some stuff in the same database table.

Reading about Spring Batch it would seems it can do this, but I'm wondering if it really can. My processing is basically as follows:

```
=> Read 20 recipients attached to job from db (where not sent)
=> Iterate over them
=> Send each the message attached to the job
=> Mark each recipient as sent
=> Save recipients back to database
```

Now I read that Spring Batch can read from a database and then do something with whatever it got, but my main gripe is the assignment. Since there may be multiple jobs at one time and each can only do a specific set of recipients. Additionally the processing involves a message that is also specific to the job. The relationships look like this:

```
Job -> hasMany -> Recipient -> belongsTo -> Job
Job -> hasOne -> Message -> belongsTo -> Job
```

Since Spring Batch doesn't expose the actual job and just keeps metadata somewhere, I feel like it would be hard to assign stuff to the job specifically, especially if the job is invoked manually after manually adding recipients and message.

Is there a good Spring Batch tutorial out there? All of them seem to use the same flat file example or an example where they read from a DB and write to a file.

Comment: Do you really need Spring Batch here? It looks like a simple `stream` on a result set from the database can handle everything without additional dependencies on libraries..

Comment: Have you looked at the samples?